# Can't share URL on social networks via their sharer

Tags: facebook, twitter, google-plus, share, social-networking

When I am trying to share a URL via Facebook, Twitter or G+ they trim the URL in the wrong way. 
For example when I press the link:

- "www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=mysite.com/index.php?page=item&id=33140"
- "twitter.com/share?url=mysite.com/index.php?page=item&id=33140"
- "plus.google.com/share?url=mysite.com/index.php?page=item&id=33140"

They all throw away the last part: "&id=33140" and try to share "mysite.com/index.php?page=item" page which doesn't exist on my website.

How do I force them to process the whole URL?

Comment: what´s your real url for testing?

Comment: looks good in the fb debugger, but i did not find any og tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to percent encode your URL to look like this: `http%3A%2F%2Fzabor.kg%2Findex.php%3Fpage%3Ditem%26id%3D33688`.

E.g. https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fzabor.kg%2Findex.php%3Fpage%3Ditem%26id%3D33688

The reason it sort of worked is because the sites would read `plus.google.com/share?url=mysite.com/index.php?page=item&id=33140` as having a query parameter of `url` AND a query parameter of `id`. Because the `&` is not encoded servers think it's ending the `url` parameter and not part of the `url` value.